# Autodesk FORGE | Digital twin

Tags: autodesk-forge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oygyE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0XGS.png)

Hi everyone, I am learning FORGE and trying to remake the Digital Twin (the link below).

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-digital-twin

Even I enter the required environments of FORGE ID, SECRET, URN. But I could not run the code. It returned with this notification.

Could you please help me to solve these problems?
Thank you,

Luan

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your case could be the urn you're using.

The model urn has to be base64 encoded. You can try encoding your urn and running the application again.